# PostgreSQL: how to specify WHERE condition with only date value for a column of type time stamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL database which has a column of type timestamp. Now I need to get data of all fields by specifying only date part of the timestamp column. How can I do this via SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast your column to `date`:

```
select ...
from ...
where the_timestamp_column::date = date '2017-01-28';
```

[The cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) using `::date` is Postgres specific syntax. If you prefer ANSI SQL, use an explicit `cast()`

```
select ...
from ...
where cast(the_timestamp_column as date) = date '2017-01-28';
```

Note that the above condition won't make use of an index on `the_timestamp_column`. If you need that, either create an index on the expression or use a range query:

```
select ...
from ...
where the_timestamp_column >= timestamp '2017-01-28 00:00:00'
  and the_timestamp_column < timestamp '2017-02-01 00:00:00';
```